# Firefox transition issues

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to do this effect on my site:

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPzarw

<svg width="100" height="100">
   <g id="cross_svg">
    <rect id="Rectangle-1"  x="0" y="0" width="48" height="2" fill="transparent"></rect>
    <rect id="Rectangle-2"  x="0" y="14" width="48" height="2" fill="transparent"></rect>
    <rect id="Rectangle-4"  x="0" y="28" width="48" height="2" fill="transparent"></rect>
  </g>    
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  display: block;
  margin: 15% auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
svg g {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
svg rect {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  fill: #E04681;
}
svg g {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var svg = $('svg');
  var lines = svg.find('rect');
  var line_first = $('svg rect:nth-child(1)')
  var line_second = $('svg rect:nth-child(2)')
  var line_third = $('svg rect:nth-child(3)')
  var i = true;

  svg.on('click', function(){
    if (i) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).find("g").addClass('gotcha')

        line_first.css({
          'transform':'rotate(45deg)',
          'left':'50%',
          'top':'50%',
          'width':'200px',
          // This line BELONGS to @dervondenbergen :D 
          // Enjoy your propriety my friend.
          'transform-origin': 'left bottom'
        })
        line_third.css({
          'transform':'rotate(-45deg) translate(-50%,-50%)',
          'left':'50%',
          'top':'50%'
        })
        line_second.css('opacity','0')
      },005)
    } else {
      setTimeout(function(){
        line_first.attr('style', '');
        line_third.attr('style', '');
        line_second.css('opacity','1')
      },005)
    }
    i=!i; 
  });
});
```

If that link doesn't work it is the SVG version from this page:
http://lukyvj.github.io/menu-to-cross-icon/

This works great in chrome and safari but when I tried it in firefox it was broken. In firefox it works, but its almost like it moved the line so it is an X without the bottom left leg. This is on the mobile version of firefox as well. Is there any special coding that needs to be done to allow this to work in firefox?

Comment: did you try -moz-transition: 10s;?

Comment: Yes, that didn't help, it's not that it isn't transitioning in firefox, its that it is not rendering right. It's like the part of the x that goes from bottom left to top right shrinks or is offset